# Upgrade to SQL Server 2014 from 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

We are currently running SQL Server 2008 R2 and want to upgrade to 2014 but we need to leave some DBs at 2008 so we have decided to create a separate 2014 server and just migrate some DBs to it.  Is there a way to script all the server settings such as Linked servers, users, scheduled jobs without doing each one individually?  Can I clone or copy the whole instance somehow.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to leave them at 2008? You could just leave them at compatibility level 100 on a 2014 instance and it won't use the 2014 features. Are you worried about the new cardinality estimator?

Comment: We are using an older version of a third party software package that says it has not tested their software with 2014.

Comment: I would check with the vendor and see if the DBs would be fine in compatibility mode. Shot in the dark, but will save you some work.

Comment: Kris, I am not worried about the cardinality estimator.  Should I be?

Comment: On 2014? Yes. The cardinality estimator is different and can cause some queries to perform very poorly. We are going to 2014 next year and we are not going to the 2014 compatibility level until we can test it on one of our development servers. It changes how the optimizer estimates how many rows are returned from each query. Some queries get much better, some can get worse. Always worth it to test first.

Comment: @Kris To be fair, the number of regressions compared to the number of improvements is extremely, extremely small. And there are many ways to work around it without being afraid of the version (trace flags for query level, and compatibility for database level).

Comment: Agreed and a good point. Still worth it to test first to make sure nothing unexpected occurs, in my opinion.

Comment: Oh of course, but your initial comment sounded like it was meant to inflict fear :-)

Comment: @Paul another thing you could consider, which may be less work over all, is to add a second instance for those databases that your vendor can't support on > 2008. There's no way to keep a 2014 database with the 2008 structure, only the compatibility level, which is a very different thing. That said, there isn't a whole lot that can break, unless they were relying on syntax that required 80 compatibility level. Are all the databases currently in 100?

Comment: I am leaning toward just upgrading the whole server to 2014. I agree with @AaronBertrand that I don't think there is anything that will break. I have never done a DB upgrade.  Does anybody recommend a site that has instructions on how to do this?

Comment: One of the issues is that 2014 no longer supports linked servers to a SQL 2000 database.  We have several of these that are going to be retired soon.